# Columnstore index in warehouse table when selecting all columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, columnstore, warehouse

I have warehouse table with around 600 000 rows, and 20 columns. Number of rows tend to grow pretty fast. I usually need to execute just this query:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE EventDate BETWEEN @Date1 AND @Date2
```

Currently I have just clustered index on primary key and no more indexes. This query for a year period which returns around 200 000 rows executes around 6 minutes, which is really slow for me. Could columnstore index help me and on which column to put it, which columns to include?

Comment: Not sure it might help, but have you tried indexing 'EventDate'?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for Clustered columnstore Index or Non-Clustered Columnstore index? If it is Clustered Columnstore index you will be indexing for all the columns. In normal scenario you might not require 'Select *' revisit why you require 'select *' for all cases? Still if it is a datawarehouse workload clustered columnstore will be faster.

```
Create clustered columnstore index CI_tbl on tablename
```

Which version of sql server you are using? This feature is available from SQL 2014 where in 2012 you might need to use non clustered columnstore index.

Comment: Actually I realised that I user Azure standard tier, and that column store indexes are available just in premium tier.